# Array method causing JS to entirely not work. How to save values into 2d array and show it?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

This works now thanks to the great help of Thunda and ArtyMcFly.
For the entire code please look here: http://plnkr.co/edit/Imcl53?p=info
Thanks for this suggestion Thunda.
First please let me apologize for this sheer amount of code. I just don't know how else to explain my problem in its entirety...

I am new to JS but not programming. I want to do the following:

A user puts his firstname, lastname, age and selects his gender. With a click on the Start button an object is created based on the constructor `Mitarbeiter`. So far everything is working except that I want to save the values into a 2D-Array. 
`runningNr` works as a counter as well as an ID. Afterwards I want to show the 2D array in a table.

My problem: obviously my `saveToArray()` and `showArray()` methods cause my entire JS code to not work anymore. I tested this by commenting out both methods and the respective `this.saveToArray = saveToArray()` and `this.showArray = showArray()`.

I also am not too sure how to actually implement my `showArray()` method but if I can't even save the values there is no point in thinking about that yet. :/

In addition I am only allowed to do this task with JS.

```
var runningNr = 0;
var employee = new Array(); // 2D-Array

// Konstruktor
function Mitarbeiter(f, l, a, g) //f = forename, l = lastname, a = age, g = gender
{
    var fname = f;
    var lname = setLName(l);
    var age = a;
    var gender;
    if (g == "Mann")
        gender = false;
    else
        gender = true;
    this.forename = getFName();
    this.lastname = getLName();
    this.age = getAge();
    this.gender = getGender();
    var total = runningNr + 1; // total of objects. runningNr +1 cause runningNr starts at 0
    this.total = getTotalObj();
    var checkboxes = document.forms.meinFormular.elements.gender;
    this.saveToArray = saveToArray();
    /* this.showArray = showArray(); */

    // Getters coming your way


    // Setters coming your way
    function setLName(x)
    {
        lname = x;
    }

    function saveToArray(runningNr, fname, lname, age, gender)
    {
        employee[Id] = new Array();
        employee[Id]["ID"] = runningNr
        employee[Id]["Firstname"] = fname;
        employee[Id]["Lastname"] = lname;
        employee[Id]["Age"] = age;
        employee[Id]["Gender"] = gender;
        runningNumber++; // Increment as this is the ID as well as the row of 2D-Array
    }

    function showArray() // Creating a table to show all informations about employees
    {
        var myTable = "<table>";
        myTable += "<tr>";
        myTable += "<th> ID </th>";
        myTable += "<th> Vorname </th>";
        myTable += "<th> Nachname </th>";
        myTable += "<th> Alter </th>";
        myTable += "<th> IstFrau </th>";
        myTable += "</tr>";

        for (var i = 0; i <= runningNumber; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
            {
                myTable += "<tr>";
                myTable += "<td>"
                employee[i][j]
                "</td>";
            }
            myTable += "</tr>";
        }
        myTable += "</table>";

        document.getElementById("showContent").innerHTML = myTable;
    }
}

function createObject(fname, lname, a, g)
{
    this.g = g[g.selectedIndex].text; // Selected gender (Mann or Frau) is given as a parameter  to Mitarbeiter();
    var obj = new Mitarbeiter(fname, lname, a, this.g);
    obj.saveToArray
}

<input type="text" name="forename" id="forename" value="test">
<input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" value="test">
<input type="text" name="age" id="age" value="1"> 
<select id="gender" name="gender" size="2">
<option selected> Mann </option>
<option> Frau </option>
</select>           
<input type="button" value="Start" onclick="createObject(this.form.forename.value, this.form.lastname.value, this.form.age.value, this.form.gender)">
<input type="button" value="Show Obj" onclick="obj.showArray">

<div id="showContent">
</div>
```

Comment: One good way to share so much code is to put it in plnkr.co and post a link on stack overflow.  Then people reading it can get nicer formatting, tinker around with it, etc.

Comment: So when you are using the saveToArray are you passing in any arguments ?

Comment: @RileyLark I havent heard about plnkr.co but I will have a look at it.
@Thunda obj.saveToArray calls the public variable `this.saveToArray` which calls the method saveToArray(). Being part of the constructor I believe the method will take the private variables fname, lname, age, gender and the global variable runningNr. So yes arguments are passed. Except this is a misinterpreting of myself :/ please correct me if so!

Comment: @Takeru I don't think it works like that I think you are just going to have undefined variables being passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found several issues. (Please see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5DmE/) for working code... normally you are supposed to separate the functionality but it was doing something odd so I threw everything into the HTML slot for a lack of time. the code displays the employee(s) after you've created the employee and select to show)

You need `<form>` tags surrounding your input values.

Your `saveToArray()` method was using javascript object syntax `employee[Id]["STRING"] = value` where I think simply replacing the strings with indexes should do the trick.

Otherwise you'll have to change it to an array of objects so `employee[Id] = new Array()` to `employee[Id] = {}` and in `showArray()` you'll have to do a `for(var key in employee[i])` which iterates through the keys of a javascript object.

Also, `Id` is never defined anywhere. you're never passing parameters to `this.saveToArray`

```
function saveToArray(runningNr, fname, lname, age, gender)
{
    var Id = runningNr; //This works for Id, not sure if it is what you wanted though.
    employee[Id] = new Array();
    employee[Id][0] = runningNr
    employee[Id][1] = fname;
    employee[Id][2] = lname;
    employee[Id][3] = age;
    employee[Id][4] = gender;
    this.runningNr++; // Increment as this is the ID as well as the row of 2D-Array
}
```

Also, there were some issues with scope. I moved `showArray()` so it was global and changed some of the syntax.

```
function showArray() // Creating a table to show all informations about employees
{
    var myTable = "<table>";
    myTable += "<tr>";
    myTable += "<th> ID </th>";
    myTable += "<th> Vorname </th>";
    myTable += "<th> Nachname </th>";
    myTable += "<th> Alter </th>";
    myTable += "<th> IstFrau </th>";
    myTable += "</tr>";

    for (var i = 0; i < runningNr; i++)
    {
        myTable += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j <= employee[i].length; j++)
        {

            myTable += "<td>"+employee[i][j]+"</td>";
        }
        myTable += "</tr>";
    }
    myTable += "</table>";

    document.getElementById("showContent").innerHTML = myTable;
}
```

Comment: Was about to answer and put the undefined variables but you got it covered.

Comment: Thank you very much. I incorporated almost everything. Finally this works now. :)

Comment: Happy to be of assistance! now that you have a working copy you can play around/change things and get things closer to your expectations =] good luck and have fun!